# Neo4J - Cypher: Collect Several Return Values to avoid duplicates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some problems with a Cypher query.
Assume you have a small Graph like this one:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/hi39sj

And as a Query I want to use

```
MATCH (A:Crew)-[i:KNOWS*]->(B:Crew)
WHERE A.name='1' AND B.name='2' 
RETURN A,B,i
```

The result contains 3 rows, but i want only one. 
The first column should contain '1', the second one '2' and the third should contain all relationships between 1 and 2 (collected in a array would be the best).

I tried to solve this with Collect but i did not get it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood you sort of answered your own question - use collect..

```
MATCH (A:Crew)-[i:KNOWS*]->(B:Crew)
WHERE A.name='1' AND B.name='2'
RETURN A,B,COLLECT(i) AS rels
```

Comment: Haha, Thank you. I tried to collect A and B, but never throught of collecting the RelationShips ^^,